# IBM X3500 M3 upgrading Intel Xeon E5507 and 5520 Compatibility

Tags: central-processing-unit, ibm

I have an [IBM X3500 M3 IBM server](http://www-07.ibm.com/systems/includes/content/x/hardware/tower/x3500m3/index.html) with one processor installed. I want to add another processor to the server.

I want to know if this is this fully compatible with already installed processor E5507. Or any other compatible server processor suggestions.

IBM X3500 M3
Motherboard: 69Y4357
Processor:  [Intel Xeon E5507](http://ark.intel.com/products/37100/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5507-%284M-Cache-2_26-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI%29?wapkw=e5507) @ 2.27GHz, socket LGA 1366, 4 cores.

Memory: 
DDR3 Dual Channel
Frequency  1600 MHz
16MB

Answer (score 0):

You want to use two identical processors. Since you already have an E5507 you want to add another E5507.

The alternative is to upgrade both CPUs. In which case you need to:

- Check that the CPU does not draw more power than the motherboard can safely supply. (The [current CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/37100/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5507-%284M-Cache-2_26-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI%29?wapkw=e5507) has an 80 Watt TPD).
  [edit] The board does seem to support [this 130W TDP CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/47929/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5677-%2812M-Cache-3_46-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI%29?wapkw=x5677), so that might be a moot point.
- Check that the cooling is up to specs (E.g. second CPU fan or second shroud available?)
- Check that your current firmware supports the CPU.